# Calculated Column with time element

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

I know I've read that dates and time don't do well in lists.  Does anyone know a workaround to create a calculated column that will bump the number up in the column by 1 every 24 hours.  So the column is titled # of days post-op and it will equal 0 on the first day, after 24 hours it should equal 1, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that calculated columns don't recalculate until an item is modified. So if nobody edits an item for 3 days after post-op, your calculated column will still show 0. You have 2 options within SharePoint: either show the op date and let your users calculate it in their heads, or create views that filter into 0-1 days post-op, 1-2 days post-op, etc. Another solution would be to do the calculations with JavaScript, although you'll need to do some customizing. [Here is one blog with example Javascript.](http://amitphule.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-show-days-count-after-created.html) [Here is another.](http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Countdown-Countup.aspx) Let me know if you want to go down the JavaScript route and run into problems; I'd be happy to discuss.

Answer (score 2):

As Aron mentioned if you wanted it to automatically update you'll need to configure something to periodically update the values.

Some options:

1. A SharePoint Timer Job that runs once a day to update the column.
2. A PowerShell script to update the column that runs once a day via the Windows Scheduler.